# How and why are function parameter reference kept between calls in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, function-parameter

I illustrate my problem with a piece of code:

```
def foo(n, li = []):
    if len(li) > n:
        return li
    li.append(str(len(li)))
    foo(n, li)
    return li

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo(2))
    print(foo(5))
    print(foo(2))
    print(foo(2, []))
```

I have a recursive function with a default parameter `li`. When I call the function without that parameter set, I expect it to take the default value, `[]`. So, for the third call I expect the same output as for the first call. Instead I get:

```
['0', '1', '2']
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['0', '1', '2']
```

Why is the value of `li` kept between calls to `foo`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thank you, haven't found this one.